# Who wrote this?

Tags: identification-request, russian-language

> White rose in the garden
>   Raven puppy in the night
>   Stars reflecting all Heaven
>   Looking for it, not found
>   Moving through
>   Moving through
>   Nothing left for me to do

Comment: Welcome to Literature SE! It would help greatly if you could provide additional information about this poem. When did you read it and where? Is it an old poem? Since you added the [russian-literature] tag, is this your translation or someone else's?

Comment: Rebecca, just a reminder that if you think my answer is a good one, you have the option of [accepting it](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) as your preferred answer by clicking on the check (tick) mark next to it. This is optional, but is a good signal to our user community that the Q&A format has worked well in this instance. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The only source I can find is on a fan fiction website, within a [Russian language sub-site](https://ficbook.net/readfic/7772982/19771657) devoted to the TV series "Anna Detective".

The poem appears within a 2019 fanfic short story called *Fiery Notebook* by Andrey Mizin. According to the [Google Translate version of the page](https://translate.google.com.au/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=https://ficbook.net/readfic/7772982/19771657&prev=search), a note to the text says:

> The work "Fiery Notebook" was written for the literary contest of
>   Christmas stories in 2019 of the group "Anna Detective".

The poem itself is given in English within the Russian text, but it's not clear whether it's an original poem by Mizin, or has been borrowed (perhaps from a translation, given the slight changes to wording) from some other source. Mizin's wording is:

> White flask rose in the garden
>   Raven puppy in the night
>   Stars reflecting all the heaven
>   Looking forward no fight
>
> Stars reflecting all the heaven
>   They expect me to fall through
>
> Moving through
>   Moving through…